# Inherited overridden method not being called

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Why does the `depositmoney()` method within the operation method of the account class call the `depositmoney()` of the account class and not the one from the `Sav_account` class? The direct call to `depositmoney()` method calls method of the sub-class which is obvious. But can't understand why the indirect call from `operations()` does not give the expected result.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int temp = 0;

class account
{
protected:
    string name;
    double balance;
    int AccNo;
public:
    void operations()
    {
        int r = 0;
        do{
            cout << "1.DEPOSIT" << endl;
            cout << "2.WITHDRAW" << endl;
            cout << "3.CHECK BALANCE" << endl;
            cout << "0.EXIT" << endl;
            cin >> r;
            switch(r)
            {
            case 1:this->depositmoney();
                break;
            case 2:this->withdraw();
                break;
            case 3:this->displaybalance();
                break;
            case 0:cout << "Exiting" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        while(r != 0);
    }
    account(string Name, double bal)
    {
        name = Name;
        balance = bal;
        AccNo = temp++;
    }
    void displaybalance()
    {
        cout << "name :" << name << endl;
        cout << "A/C" << AccNo << endl;
        cout << "your balance is " << balance << endl;
    }
    void depositmoney()
    {
        float deposit;
        cout << "enter deposit" << endl;
        cin >> deposit;
        balance += deposit;
    }
protected:
    void withdraw()
    {
        float withdrawal;
        cout << "enter witdrawal amount" << endl;
        cin >> withdrawal;
        if(balance >= withdrawal)
        {
            balance -= withdrawal;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "insufficient funds" << endl;
        }
    }
};

class Sav_account :public account
{
private:
    double const CI = 5;
    void depositinterest()
    {
        balance += balance*CI / 100;
    }
public:
    Sav_account(string Name, double bal) :account(Name, bal)
    {
        AccType = 0;
    }
    void depositmoney()
    {
        account::depositmoney();
        depositinterest();
    }
};

void main()
{
    Sav_account *account1 = new Sav_account("Shaw", 50000);
    account1->operations();// DEPOSIT RESULTS IN NO INTEREST
    account1->displaybalance();
    account1->depositmoney(); // **DEPOSIT FUNCTION OF Sav_account CALLS                      interest function**
    account1->displaybalance();
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Please add an appropriate tag for the language you are using.

Comment: the code doesn't compile: `AccType = 0;` "error: ‘AccType’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: I deleted some lines before uploading the question and it looks like i forgot that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not polymorphic. You have no polymorphic functions and have not overridden anything. (You have hidden functions instead). As such, calling `depositmoney();` from a function of `account` will call `account::depositmoney()`.

To make a class polymorphic you need to use virtual functions. Any function that you want to have polymorphic behaviour needs to be declared as `virtual` in the base class, e.g. in `account` here:

```
virtual void depositmoney() {
```

In the derived class, since C++11, you can write:

```
void depositmoney() override
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

which will cause a compiler error if you accidentally hide a function when you are trying to override it. (Although I'm guessing that you are using a compiler that doesn't support C++11, since most of those will also reject `void main`).

---

Also, any polymorphic base class should have a virtual destructor, i.e. `virtual ~account() {}` otherwise the code `account *x = new Sav_account("Shaw", 50000); delete x;` would cause undefined behaviour.

`void main` is illegal, `main` must have a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There *aren't* any overridden methods in your classes; you haven't made any of them `virtual`.